# Update the database by TCP or HTTP?

Tags: database, http, tcp, web, gps

I am making a GPS tracking website and I have already tried to use TCP and HTTP method to save the values to the database. Both worked. However, I wonder should I save the GPS coordinates to the database via HTTP or TCP?. Which one is better? I read some articles and one of those said: "use of HTTP protocol as data sending method reduces the monthly bundle cost for the individual user and also for the small business owner". Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is an application protocol, TCP a transport protocol.
HTTP uses TCP as the transport protocol, so any HTTP connections are TCP connections.

If you instead ask yourself if you should use some HTTP based REST or even SOAP API to update the database instead of the protocol native to the database, then you should be aware that the native protocol introduces much less overhead and thus provides more performance. But, HTTP based APIs usually have less problems with firewalls in between client and database.

> I read some articles and one of those said: "use of HTTP protocol as data sending method reduces the monthly bundle cost for the individual user and also for the small business owner". Is this right?

The way you cite it here out of the context of the original article it sounds like nonsense. But it might have made sense within the context of the article. So this question can not be answered without having this context.